# No results returned from HIVE SQL Query with join on bigint column

Tags: sql, hive, inner-join, bigint

I am wondering why the below query returns no records. "theTable" appears twice and it is the same table. I just want to get, for all item_id corresponding to a specific chal_id (888888 in this case), what are all the records in that table (theTable). The query should at least return the records with that specific chal_id(888888), right?

item_id and chal_id are both bigint data type. data is the partition column so has to be included in the where clause.

Note that the where clause "chal = 888888 and date between '20200610' and '20200710'" actually returns 260k records. I have run the part inside the () to make sure that it does not return 0 record.

````
select *
FROM theTable t0 INNER JOIN
     (select item_id AS item_id_1
      from theTable
      where chal = 888888 and date between '20200610' and '20200710'
    ) t1
    ON t0.item_id = t1.item_id_1
WHERE t0.date between '20200610' and '20200720'```
````

Comment: Clearly the `where` clauses filter out all the rows.

Comment: That is not true...that where clause "chal = 888888 and date between '20200610' and '20200710'" actually returns 260k records. Let me add that to the question too.

Comment: try to comment the last `where` clause. will you have any data in that case?

Comment: by the way, looks like you don't really need `item_id_1`, so you can use `left semi join` instead of `inner join`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using semi join. The last where clause is necessary as it is a partition column. Without it the Hive sql is not running.